# DataAdapter Not updating the selected row of a Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, sqldataadapter

I have checkbox colum (unbound) and 2 other columns in my datagridview. There is a selectall checkbox on top of the checkbox column. When it comes to updating I loop through all the selected rows, update the datagridview and then call update via my DataAdapter. My problem is that whichever row I have clicked inside (click inside any column of that row) doesn't get updated. I've tried various things like setting the currentcell to null, making the currentcell.selected property false,

```
        using (this.daTableAdapter.Connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionStringFromControls()))
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvCompanies.Rows)
            {
                if ((row.Cells["Select"].Value != null) && ((bool)row.Cells["Select"].Value == true))
                {
                    row.Cells[3].Value = ((ComboBoxItem)cmbUserInfo.SelectedItem).Value; 
                    dgvCompanies.EndEdit(); //Have tried leaving this out
                }
            }
            int count = this.daTableAdapter.Update(myDataSet.Companies);
        }
```

My count is always one short of the number of rows that should be updating. The UI is always getting updated correctly, i.e. row.Cells[3].Value is getting set as I would expect. I've run a trace on sql profiler and the update command is not being sent for that row.

Any ideas greatly appreciated

Comment: You are changing the value in the grid but not in the DataTable.

Comment: I was updating it differently before and had wondered that. But if that was a problem can you explain why it works for the other rows and for all rows when none are selected?

Comment: Are you using a BindingSource as DataSource?

Comment: I am (but come to think of it, I might not need to be). Why?